# Show modal page on only a portion of the screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog, toolbar

I am developing an iPad app using Xamarin.Forms. 
I would like my settingspage to be modal so it lay over the previous page like a popup.

I have been trying all solutions I could find and most of them seems to recommend me to call this from a button:

```cs
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(ModalSettingsPage);
```

What happens when I use it is that my settingspage comes in from below as a modal page but not as a popup, it covers the entire screen.

This is my current code:

```cs
 //Setup button (action bar)
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
            {
                // Text = "Setup",
                Icon = "settings1.png",
                Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Default,
                Command = new Command(() => Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ModalSettingsPage())) //Action to perfome on click , open modal view
            });
```

Also, does anyone now if there is any good way to positions the ToolbarItems? I have two items and would like each one to be positioned at each side, but by default they are both positioned to the right.

Comment: It sounds like you are really asking 2 questions here: (1) how to achieve a less-than-full-screen modal, (2) how to position iOS UIToolbarItem. I believe that question (2) is easy on native iOS and hard on Xamarin Forms - it can be achieved with a custom renderer that sets the `LeftBarButtonItem` and `RightBarButtonItem` property on the `NavigationItem` property of the top view controller (reference - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21004/navigation-bar-left-toolbar-button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing pre-made in Forms to give you a popup like I think you want. Instead, you would have to create this or use a third-party solution. For example, [here](https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup) is a "popup" implementation that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you! 
I am little new to using xamarin on windows, and I actually don't know how to import/ download a github libary into my current project. 
For Apple I usually use cocoaPods for that. 
I haven't found any information about how to do that on windows, do you happen to now any tutorial or any tool I can use?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this has been distributed as a library. You'll have to download the code and add the code files to your project.

Answer (score 7):

With the evolution of Forms (currently 4.5.0), it has now become simple to push a modalpage which is not fullscreen. Use the following in your code-behind of your xaml contentpage:

```html
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;

namespace YourAppWithAModalPage
{
    public class ModalPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ModalPage()
        {
            // iOS Solution for a ModalPage (popup) which is not fullscreen
            On<iOS>().SetModalPresentationStyle(UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet);
        }
    }
}
```